# How to copy files/folders using cp command?

Tags: node.js, shell, cp

I have a folder, `cs-template` with the structure something like this:

```
cs-template
  |_
    public
     |_
       assets
        |_
          img
           |_
             example.png
     |_
       robots.txt

  |_
    src
     |_
       components
        |_
          Accessibility
           |_
             Accessibility.js
     |_
       routes
        |_
          AppRoutes.js
     |_
       App.js

  |_
    package.json
```

I want to copy everything inside the `cs-template` folder into `new_dest1` folder. Both of them are defined at the same level. I'm calling an HTTP request basically, after which I want to copy the contents. So, in a controller for a route, I have defined the following logic:

```
'use strict';


var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Task = mongoose.model('CampusStore');

exports.list_all_campus_stores = function(req, res) {
  Task.find({}, function(err, campus_store) {
    
    const system = require('system-commands');
  
    system('cp -r  ./cs-template/**/ ./new_dest1').then(output => {
      console.log(output)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    });

    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(campus_store);
  });
};
```

`cp -r  ./cs-template/* ./new_dest1` copies only `public` folder (that too, incomplete) and `package.json` file.

`cp -r  ./cs-template/**/* ./new_dest1` copies everything accept the parent `public` and `src` folders (meaning the folders/files within these are getting copied but the folders themselves are not) and `package.json`. What's the correct way to do?

Comment: Only copies ```package.json``` through this

Comment: How about `cp -r  ./cs-template/ ./new_dest1` ?

Comment: What happens when you run this command in a terminal? Does it throw any permission issues or anything? I think first you should try the command over the terminal before getting the same into your code.

Comment: ```cp -r ./cs-template/ ./new_dest1``` this when I run from terminal copies everything correctly. However, when I run it through code, it doesn't copy ```src``` folder and miss some folders/files in the ```public``` folder. What can I do any idea?

Comment: On Linux, read [cp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) or try `/bin/cp --help`. Consider also using [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/)

Answer (score 4):

**try this:**

You can copy the content of a folder /source to another existing folder /dest with the command

```
cp -a /source/. /dest/
```

The -a option is an improved recursive option, that preserve all file attributes, and also preserve symlinks.

The . at end of the source path is a specific cp syntax that allow to copy all files and folders, included hidden ones.

-a : Preserve the specified attributes such as directory an file mode, ownership, timestamps, if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all.

-v : Explain what is being done, detailed view.

-r : Copy directories recursively. Example

**If it's not working then use an alternate:**

There are some modules that support copying folders with their content. The most popular would be wrench.js:

// Deep-copy an existing directory

```
wrench.copyDirSyncRecursive('directory_to_copy','location_where_copy_should_end_up');
```

An alternative would be node-fs-extra:

```
fs.copy('/tmp/mydir', '/tmp/mynewdir', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("success!");
  }
});
```